# Google Map Geocoding API on load

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm looking to adjust sample google map code found here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding so it geocodes the address on page loading. So no more fixed coordinates (already loaded from my view file) and should geocode by itself with no human interaction

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
    } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're asking here. If you'd like the address to be geocoded when the page displays, there will need to be a value in the `#address` element:

```
<input type="text" id="address" value="1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW  Washington, DC 20500">
```

...and then you simply call the `initialize()` and `geocode()` functions in `window.onload` function:

```
window.onload = function() {
    initialize();
    codeAddress();
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fYbqe/

**EDIT** Updated jsFiddle that makes it a bit easier to use a custom address: http://jsfiddle.net/fYbqe/1/

Comment: Hi, it's pretty close. Anyway I can remove the default latlong on the initialize method to position marker to my custom address directly? http://jsfiddle.net/fYbqe/

Comment: @olivier Are those coordinates (-34.397, 150.644) the ones you want to start it out at? Or is there an address you want to use?

Comment: @olivier I updated the jsFiddle to make it easier to put in your own address. You should just need to replace the 1600 Pennsylvania Ave stuff in the JavaScript with the address you want to use.

Comment: I have the some problem here, I am loading five pages on iframe, one of them the page is the google map geocode, i am calling a function on window onload to geocode the address but that funtion fire when first page load in the iframe, i tried the document.ready,wind.load,if($(div).is(:visible)) but every thing fires on first page load on the iframe, the googlemap is on number three when we click next  3 times then googlemap turn come!!